# SQL Date range using dynamic params

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have custom table, which stipulates in days how long to retain records for. I need to know how I can pass in a variable into a BETWEEN statement to returns only the records from today inclusive, -variable.

```
WHERE (MessageDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), - 7))
```

-7 in this instance would be 7 days from today, and is meant to be a parameter which I pass in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `DATEDIFF` function, you can use just `DATEADD`, for which the correct parameter order you can find [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

So, your WHERE clause can look like this:

```
DECLARE @parameter INTEGER
SET @paramenter = -7
...
WHERE
    (MessageDate BETWEEN GETDATE ()
                     AND DATEADD(day, @parameter, GETDATE())
    )
```

Here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29083). (updated fiddle)

**Edit:**

Also, the BETWEEN part of the query should have an older date first ( `DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()` ) and then a more recent date ( `GETDATE()` ).

This is why, if you will always have a negative parameter to pass on, you will have to switch the order of the dates in the WHERE clause and use them like this:

```
WHERE
    (MessageDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, @parameter, GETDATE()
                 AND GETDATE())
    )
```

But, if you might have to pass both positive and negative parameters, then use this:

```
WHERE
    (MessageDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, @parameter, GETDATE()
                 AND GETDATE())
     OR
     MessageDate BETWEEN GETDATE ()
                     AND DATEADD(day, @parameter, GETDATE())
    )
```

Using `OR` you will have both cases covered, the one in which you send a positive parameter and the one where you send a negative parameter.

These cases are mutually exclusive, so only one condition will ever return results.

Comment: I cannot see that fiddle

Comment: "parameter which I pass in": may want to show some code or a link to stored procedures and how to call them.

Comment: Ok, so using this Radu, I dont see any records. I have one records for today, and six for the 20th. date format in the table is 2014-01-27 (for the single value) and 2014-01-20 for the six

Comment: This is the only way I could get it to return the values:

WHERE (CONVERT(date, dbo.Messages.MessageDate, 103) BETWEEN DATEADD(day, - 7, CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 103)) AND CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 103))

Answer (score 1):

Substraction from `GETDATE()` results in DAYS, therefore you can use the following:

```
DECLARE @param INTEGER
SET @param = 7
--
WHERE cast(MessageDate as datetime) >= GETDATE()- @param
      AND  cast(MessageDate as datetime)<= GETDATE()
```